# Where should I ask a question about abstract physics/economics/information theory that I invented?

Tags: discussion, non-mainstream-physics

I wrote [this](http://www.lind-i.com/Docs/EconomicCircuitry.pdf) and a couple other related papers and I'd like to discuss, where should I go?

Comment: Your paper may be a bit advanced for us. I could not understand a word of it.

Comment: Always the diplomat @JohnRennie. I'm impressed.

Comment: Please explain your notation and provide proofs for your theorems. Also, I would gladly discuss your theory in chat!

Answer (score 9):

Not here, and probably not anywhere on Stack Exchange. These sites are not for discussion. You should find some place that admits reviews of original research. (Well, *actually* what you should do is try to get it published, but that's a whole separate issue.)

You could try bringing it up in [chat](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) to see if anyone would care to discuss it with you, but no guarantees.

Comment: Any suggestions on sites that will do that, I will bring it up in chat as well.

Comment: I can't think of any offhand.